# Search in view results and sort column

Tags: sorting, xpages

I have a panel being used as a datasource for a repeat control. In that panel, the 'search in view results' is computed to a FT search expression and the column name and sort order is set.

[image: screenshot]

If the following property (Click on column header to sort) is not set on the view column that is being used for the sort, I get a 500 error on the page. When I set it, the page loads and the results are sorted  as expected.

I stumbled across this post in the forum where Bob Cross mentioned having to check that parameter in the view column.

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/xpagesforum.nsf/xpTopicThread.xsp?documentId=9FE4E37D27400C1585257D3800734372

Anyone who can explain the correlation between the two? I'm stumped.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works as designed. To return anything sorted Domino requires an index on that column. The property "click on column header to sort" tells Domino to build an index for that row. Sort indexes are not build on the fly, so when you set the FTSearch to be sorted by a column that doesn't have an index, then you get the error "column not indexed" which translates into an error 500. You can try manually: open the view itself. Click on a header where the sort property is set and look at the URL. Then modify that URL to use a column without the property and you will see.

Having said that. Be careful with your FTSearches. There is but ONE full text index. When you ftsearch in a view, you actually do a ftsearch in the database and then check if the hits are also in that view. That might be slower than a db.ftsearch

If sorting is what you are after, you could use a Bean and load the results into a Java collection that has unlimited variations of sort capabilities.

Comment: Thanks, Stephan. I would have expected the index to be created when I clicked on the Sort (Ascending) property of the column.